# Including more than one JS file in a single adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio

I wanted to know if it is possible to add more than one JS file in an adapter implementation.

By default we get the following three files -

[image: Default setting]

I want to add one more JS like this -

[image: Needed setting]

If this is possible am I missing any step to link this to the *AdapterName*-impl.js ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add additional implementation files (or any file type, rather) to adapters in the current releases of Worklight.

I agree it is a highly wanted feature, so I will direct you to the following page where you can submit a feature request to be evaluated by Worklight product designers: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. A workaround that can get you closer to what you want is to create another adapter, add the code you want in OneMoreImpl.js to that adapter implementation file, then invoke procedures from that adapter using WL.Server.invokeProcedure as follows:

```
WL.Server.invokeProcedure({
    adapter : "AotherAdapterName",
    procedure : "ProcedureName",
    parameters : [ input ]
});
```

Comment: that is what I have been doing but was just curious to know if there was a better way to do it !